# CURL with Browser's PHPSESSID

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm trying to make an CURL request with the same session (PHPSESSID) as the client's browser. I tried a lot of things and searched for an answer but couldn't find any. This is the code I have so far:

```
session_start();
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
session_write_close();

$url="http://example.com";

$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

CURLOPT_COOKIE should set the PHPSESSID with the request but it just seems to generate a new PHPSESSID when I debug the CURL request and so it is not equal to my browser's PHPSESSID.

I also tried using the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE but they just seem to overwrite my existing browser's PHPSESSID.

Both the pages are on the same domain.

Comment: Is the site you're trying to curl PHP based? Does is use session cookies? Does it use that key? Even then, unless this is one of your own sites you're trying to curl (and have session sharing), chances are that the external site's ids will not match your sites anyway.

Comment: @JonStirling The site is one of my own, so it is on the same domain name. And it does use session cookies.

Comment: Same domain, different subdomain?

Comment: @JonStirling both on the same subdomain. I checked both pages with Dev Tools and both have the same PHPSESSID.

Comment: That begs the question then, why are you using curl at all? Can you not just call the code used in the other request?

Comment: @JonStirling Well it's an open source cms which I don't have experience with yet, so I thought this would be the easier way around. But it seems weird that this CURLOPT_COOKIE is not working for me?